# Azure DevOps Boards 'Done' column orders in descending work item ID - Scrum

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

When I move a work item into the 'Done' column on my DevOps Team Board, it wont add it to the top of the list, it will vanish down the list somewhere. Today, I realised the Done column is ordered by work item ID (descending).

I have played around with "Card Reordering" settings with no useful outcome. When I create a new DevOps project, I don't see this effect and it orders how I would expect (work items most recently moved to "Done" state are placed at the top of the Done column).